# Получить несколько рандомных записей из базы

Tags: php, mysql

Не могу понять, как использовать рандом, при выборке из базы. Необходимо получить 4 рандомных значения, при обращении к функции. Прошу помочь(

```
$get = self::select('*', ["ORDER"=>["id"=>"DESC"], "LIMIT"=>4]); //'ORDER BY RAND()'
if ($get !== null) {
 return $get;
 }
```

Comment: `SELECT column FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4` - вот пример, от него и крутите, ибо сложно вам помочь, мало информации на чем пишите и тд.

Comment: @Manitikyl   Я пытался написать запросы, но они не работают(   использую medoo php.